# How to deal with custom nginx.conf files in Amazon ECS?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I basically have two docker images: nginx image and a php image, that I want to upload to ECS. Both are run by a docker-compose.
The nginx has a myapp.conf file that I want to copy from somewhere into the container's `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder.

Whats the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your own nginx image and use the COPY command.

```
FROM nginx

COPY myapp.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Build it:

```
docker build -t mynginximg .
```

and use it in your compose files.

Comment: Cool Thanks. I'm doing that but I'm just not sure where to put the myapp.conf so that my dockerfiles can reach them from ECS? It looks like you can only load up images to ECS and not containers?

Comment: We usually manage this by having a special git repository containing the configurations. This way I can prepare a build pipeline to automate changes. Anyway it does not really matter where you store the files.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'm a noob and that's what I was thinking but wasn't sure if there were any sort of AWS preferred ways to go about it.

Comment: Not really, you can store the new image on their registry and have the registry associated with your ECS. The image generation can be done from your machine. If you think the question is answered, can you also accept it?